Ruby gsub capturing groups
This is my input (stored in content variable):
<p>some text</p>
[image=content_001]Some alt/legend text[/image]
<div>some div</div>

This is my desired output:
<p>some text</p>
<div>
  <img src="blog/content/content_001.webp" alt="Some alt/legend text" />
  <p>Some alt/legend text</p>
</div>
<div>some div</div>


This where I am so far:
  r = %r{\[image=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/image\]}

  content.gsub(r, content_tag(:div) do
    image_tag('blog/content/?.webp', alt: '?') +
    content_tag(:p, '?')
  end).html_safe

By what should I replace the '?' to use the captured groups?

Can ?2 contain more nested tags? or is it fine to disallow square brackets in ?2? (Not allowing nested tags would make this possible with regex.)

@Dogbert there is no nested tags.

Replacing two placeholders seems pretty straight forward, what have you tried so far?

Post an example of an actual HMTL chunk you want to change, what you've done so far with it, and what the chink should like like after you've changed it. Positive and negative examples often help, too. HTML can be tricky, so if you haven't already parsed it with Nokogiri or REXML you may not have the strings you think you have, and regular expressions have their own edge cases too.

We are writing the HTML ourselves, the exact strings are the ones from the first post.
What we need is simply to write a gsub where we can have 2 variable that we can reuse on on the final string

@DanielCosta oh, so your actual string contains ?1 and ?2 literally? I assumed those were placeholders. When translating that template string into actual HTML, where do the values for ?1 and ?2 come from?

@Stefan I rewrote the question to be straight forward and not use pseudo values. This is a real example.

@Todd A. Jacobs I added a real example now.

Your edits improve the post a lot. IMHO, complex text transformations should be a multi-step process to enabled fine-tuning and debugging, not a single complicated regexp. If the question is re-opened by the community, you can expect my answer to address it that way.

Based on your comments you want to replace the "exact string" [image=?1]?2[/image] so that the output is "<div>#{image_tag(?1, alt: ?2)} <p>#{?2}</p><div>".
In that case the following should work for you:
r = /\[image=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/image\]/
str =<<DOC
I have [image=?1]?2[/image] 
with many other [image=?3]?4[/image] 
and I need to replace the [image=?1]?2[/image] 
with other formatting
DOC

result = str.gsub(r,'<div>#{image_tag(\1, alt: \2} <p>#{\2}</p></div>')

puts result
#=> I have <div>#{image_tag(?1, alt: ?2} <p>#{?2}</p></div>
# with many other <div>#{image_tag(?3, alt: ?4} <p>#{?4}</p></div>
# and I need to replace the <div>#{image_tag(?1, alt: ?2} <p>#{?2}</p></div>
# with other formatting

UPDATE
Based on the context change to the question you need to use the block form of gsub and the "special variables" $1 and $2, which refer to capture groups 1 and 2 respectively (See globals for more information).
r = /\[image=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/image\]/
str =<<DOC
<p>some text</p>
[image=content_001]Some alt/legend text[/image]
<div>some div</div>
DOC

result = str.gsub(r) do
  content_tag(:div) do
    # had to create an img tag rather than the image_tag helper 
    # to avoid appending /images to the src path
    tag("img",src: "blog/content/#{$1}.webp", alt: $2) +
    content_tag(:p, $2)
  end
end.html_safe

puts result
#=> <p>some text</p>
# <div><img src="blog/content/content_001.webp" alt="Some alt/legend text" /><p>Some alt/legend text</p></div>
# <div>some div</div>


Yes, I tried to keep it simple but apparently it's just confusing. In realty my content will be [image=content/sun.jpg]Some alternate text and legend text[/image] 
In short the goal was to know how to capture 2 distinct groups and use then on the "replaced" string. I tried your method with content_tag but \2 doesn't seen accepted as a variable

@DanielCosta You need $2 rather than \2, and will also need the block form of gsub.

Thanks! This is it. How do you call those $1 variables. I want to read the documentation about that and look further how it works.

@DanielCosta I linked to the globals documentation in the post but $N variables (excepting $0) are documented as "The Nth group of the last successful match."
